# KSH - example requested of "\n" replacement in parameter expansion

Tags: ksh

I am looking for a working example of "\n" replacement in parameter expansion in KSH. The below is from the man page.

```
${parameter/pattern/string}
${parameter// pattern/string}
${parameter/#pattern/string}
${parameter/%pattern/string}
```

Expands parameter and replaces the longest match of pattern with the specified string. ***Each occurrence of \n in string is replaced by the portion of parameter that matches the nth sub-pattern.***

Thanks! dvenus

Answer (score 1):

The `\n` is not a newline but a numbered back reference.
As an example I start with a `sed` command:

```
par="String with =field1= and =field2= that you want to switch"
sed -r 's/(=.*=).*(=.*=).*/\2 and \1 switched./' <<< "${par}"
# result
String with =field2= and =field1= switched.
```

Without `sed` (`ksh` feature)

```
echo "${par/@(=[^=]*=)*@(=[^=]*=)*/\2 and \1 switched.}"
```